# Float to String format specifier

Tags: c#, parsing, numbers, string-formatting

I have some float values I want to convert to a string, I want to keep the formatting the same when converting, i.e. 999.0000(float) -> 999.0000(String).  My problem is when the values contain an arbitrary number of zeroes after the decimal point, as in the previous example, they are stripped away when converting to a string, so the result I actually end up with is 999.

I looked at the format specifiers for the `toString()` method on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#RFormatString), the RoundTrip ('R') specifier looks like it will produce what I want, but it is only supported for Single, Double and BigInt variables.  Is there a format specifier like this for float variables??  Or would it be easier to just convert the values to doubles?

UPDATE: Just for clarity, the reason why I want to keep the trailing zeroes is because I'm doing a comparison of decimal places, i.e. I'm comparing the number of digits after the decimal place between two values.  So for example, 1.00 and 1.00000 have a different number of digits after the decimal point.  I know it's a strange request, it's for work and the requirement is coming from on high.

UPDATE 2-3-11:

I was thinking about this too hard, I'm reading the numbers from a txt file and then parsing them as floats, I'm going to modify the program to check whether the string values are decimals or whole numbers.  Sorry for wasting your time, although this was very insightful.

Comment: how many digits after the decimal point? if you want to keep that dynamic, assuming the value is correct float, then use .ToString("G")

Comment: The digits will vary, to keep it simple, I'd say the range of digits after the decimal point may be anywhere between 1 and 5.

Comment: .ToString("G") is best for variable range

Comment: Tried the "G" specifier, but when a number like 999.0 is encountered, it returns 999.  I want to keep the trailing zeroes, as a string I want to have it be "999.0"

Comment: kingrichard2005, there is no distinction between 999.0000 and 999.0 for the `float`/`System.Single` type (they are the same); they are only values, completely oblivious to formatting. Where is this 999.0000 coming from? Where are you *seeing* it?

Comment: If you want the string as it is in the text file and you don't need the actual value for some calculation, why don't you just read the values as strings and not parse them to floats at all?

If you do need the values, parse them but keep the original string with it.  Either way, you can look at my post for easier formatting of numbers with format parameters to the ToString() method.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Firstly, as [Etienne says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866542/float-to-string-format-specifier/4866568#4866568), `float` in C# **is** `Single`. It is just the C# keyword for that data type.

So you can definitely do this:

```
float f = 13.5f;
string s = f.ToString("R");
```

Secondly, you have referred a couple of times to the number's "format"; numbers don't have formats, they only have *values*. **Strings** have formats. Which makes me wonder: what is this thing you have that has a format but is not a string? The closest thing I can think of would be `decimal`, which *does* maintain its own precision; however, calling simply `decimal.ToString` should have the effect you want in that case.

How about including some example code so we can see exactly what you're doing, and why it isn't achieving what you want?

Comment: Quick note: in scientific fields, it's common to distinguish "1.01e5" and "1.0100e5", as the number of trailing zeroes contributes to the number of significant digits, which expresses the precision of a measurement.

Comment: I just hope float finds someone

Answer (score 75):

Use `ToString()` with this format:

```
12345.678901.ToString("0.0000"); // outputs 12345.6789
12345.0.ToString("0.0000"); // outputs 12345.0000
```

Put as much zero as necessary at the end of the format.

Comment: Hi Aliostad, the problem with this, I want the string to be formatted exactly as a the number is formatted.  For your second example, I would want it to be "12345.0" as a string, not "12345.0000".

Comment: @kingrichard2005- what information tells you whether the float is 12345.0 or 12345.0000? They would be equivalent as floats.

Comment: I'm reading these files from a txt file.  Perhaps a better option would be to determine if the number read in as a string is a decimal number or not.

Comment: The problem is that this restricts the precision.

Comment: In my case a value of 76788.1953 got rounded to 76788.2000 when using this approach. So this method causes loss of precision.. I used ToString("R"), as answered by @Dan Tao, then I got exact precision

Answer (score 20):

You can pass a format string to the ToString method, like so:

```
ToString("N4"); // 4 decimal points Number
```

If you want to see more modifiers, take a look at [MSDN - Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

In C#, `float` is an alias for `System.Single` (a bit like `int`is an alias for `System.Int32`).