# How do I replicate Java's Float.ToString() in C#?

Tags: java, c#, floating-point

As the documentation states in Java's [Float.toString(float)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Float.html#toString(float)) method, the float is represented with only as many digits that are needed to uniquely identify the value from adjacent float values. This behaviour isn't reflected in C#'s `Single.ToString` method.

This means that in Java:

```
1500.45504 produces 1500.4551
2000.37408 produces 2000.374
```

whereas in C#:

```
1500.45504 produces 1500.455
2000.37408 produces 2000.374
```

Am I missing a flag or something in C# to replicate Java's behaviour? I can only use floating points, so using more precision, like a double, isn't feasible in this situation. Also, I can't use the `G<num>`, or `N<num>` specifiers, because the output would vary depending on whether or not the output needs a unique digit identifier.

Comment: Seems like only a thing in .NET framework. .NET 5/6/7 produces 1500.4551 instead of 1500.455. In any case, [this might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65478282/why-net-5-0-and-framework-in-c-sharp-does-not-return-same-value#comment116009860_65478282). (?)

Comment: @Sweeper is there any way that this can be manually implemented in v4.7.2?

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely need the results to match, I would suggest not relying on the language's convenience methods.  They are two different languages and can behave how they see fit.  Nothing grantees that C# has anything built in that does what  Java's Float.toString(float) does.

If you MUST replicate the Java behavior in C# I would suggest getting the source code for that Java method (here is one example: https://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/lang/Float-source.html) and then coding a C# version yourself based on that source.

If you have the option to not use Java's Float.toString() you could maybe make life easier for yourself by instead writing your own lower-level code in each language where you can guarantee that the results are equivalent between the two languages.

In your case you may be able to do this fairly easily just using string formatting.  In Java you could maybe get away with using String.format() with specified precision or maybe the DecimalFormat class (see: [How to print a float with 2 decimal places in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538787/how-to-print-a-float-with-2-decimal-places-in-java)).

On the C# side you could maybe use ToString() (see: [Float to String format specifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866542/float-to-string-format-specifier)).

Just be very carful about any rounding.  Maybe format out to a lot of decimal places then truncate back a bit or something.  After that you could compare the resulting strings.